# Android: AsyncTask and Communicating Errors on UI thread

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I am using an Android [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to fetch some data from the web. Its a simple program (a 'crack me') that fetches bytes from random.org and displays the bytes. The program also pins random.org's public key to detect interception proxies.

I have implemented `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground`, and `onPostExecute`. These methods are required when "all things go well." When something goes wrong in `doInBackground`, I cannot display an `AlertDialog` because its not a UI thread. The interface also lacks an `onError` or similar method that executes on a UI thread.

How does one convey errors when using this class?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is create field in your AsyncTask class. If something gonna wrong put there some exception throwed:

```
class SomeAsyncTask<..> extends AsyncTask<..> {
    Exception exception = null;
    public doInBackground(...) {
        try {
            . . . 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exception = ex;
        }
    }

    public onPostExecute(...) {
        if (exception != null) {
            // process exception on UI thread
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem I am seeing is that `onPostExecute` is not called in error conditions. So even if I stashed the error away, I never know when I should display it. Perhaps my observations were wrong. Perhaps `doInBackground` should return an Object. The object is an exception on error, and a byte[] otherwise.

Comment: Seems that exception in background thread doesn't handle. Thread is dying as result of such error. Wrap try-catch around dangerous code.

Answer (score 2):

I catch the error in the `doInBackground`, save the `Exception` in a field variable and check in `onPostExecute` if an error occurred:

```
private Exception exception = null;

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
    try{
        doStuff();
    } catch (Exception ex){
        exception = ex;
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    if(exception != null){
        showException(exception);
    }
}
```

You could easily create your own interface using this code, and then implement the `doStuff` and `showException` methods when using it.

Answer (score 1):

You should return any information needed to onPostExecute() and show your dialog there. Or you can store it locally as a member of an AsyncTask subclass.

Answer (score 0):

No.  just issue a broadcast in the AsyncTask and handle the broadcast anywhere you like.  The AsyncTask just needs a Context to issue this which you can pass to it. Might want to issue as Sticky broadcast so you can recover it.